# Raspberry Pi randomly unresponsive

Tags: linux, corrupt

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, I have tried running a GitLab server on it but it seemed to be too performance expensive so I uninstalled it, I also had to cut the power of the Pi without properly shutting it down.

Since this period, my Raspberry Pi doesn't work properly anymore. It is connected to my local network by wifi, it is in headless mode so I only connect to it via SSH.

When I am able to connect to it, I can type a few commands, sometimes only a few characters, and quite quickly the pi doesn't respond anymore.
Strangely, the issue seems quite random, I was sometimes able to use it correctly during several minutes for instance.

I tried running fsck both `touch /forcefsck` and by plugging my SD card to a Linux virtual machine and running fsck but none of those options solved my issue.
I suspected a wifi connection issue but scripts that should have run at regular intervals on my Pi (with CRON) didn't seem to function properly either so wifi issue seems highly unlikely.

What should I do to find the cause of this issue and solve it?

Thank you

Comment: Can you read `journalctl -e` on your raspi?

Comment: Can you please check the load of your Raspberry (by executing `uptime` at the command line)?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ingo's comment, I found a potential cause; in my case by using `journalctl -e` I could see that my Raspberry Pi was disconnecting and reconnecting to the IPv6 network every few minutes. This seems to have something to do with the IPv6 network not being fully supported by the ISP. I just had to disable it in the router and it went back to normal.

But be sure to try using `journalctl -e` to see any unusual or frequent behaviour, and use `uptime` to see if the cores are being overloaded. (>1 is overloaded for a single core CPU, >4 is overloaded for a quad core CPU, etc.)